# When adding a reference from the GAC VS automatically changes it to a local dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have this strange issue where I add a reference to an assembly in the GAC and Visual Studio insists on changing it to a reference to a local assembly in the bin folder. I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: That... doesn't sound right.  Are you sure?  I would double check with `procexp` or Fusion to check where the assembly is loaded from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've seen this is in Visual Studio 2015 when I tried to add a reference to a project built with .NET 2.0 to a project targeting .NET 4.5. At this point, Visual Studio throws up a warning message saying it's going to use a local file reference.

This is mentioned in the MSDN page here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx

> In Visual Studio 2015, a file reference instead of a project reference is 
>   created if the target version of the .NET Framework of one project is version 
>   4.5, and the target version of the other project is version 2, 3, 3.5, or 4.0.

Might be useful to check if the .NET versions match on the referenced library and your project.

Comment: Yes that turned out to be the issue. The problem is the dev server has VS2010 so the project is limited to a lower version of .NET than the libraries we are trying to reference. I figured that out when I deleted the dll files and tried to build. This time it had to reference the ones in the GAC but the warning message was clear that the project version is lower than the libraries being referenced. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the `Copy Local` property of the reference is set to false.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to delete the .dll files altogether to stop VS from referencing them and after I did that I started getting a warning saying 
“The primary reference "xxxx" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
So it seems we need to upgrade our Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013 to be able to use these libraries in our project.